# Find the latest file from the list of files in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to grab latest file from the list of files which comes with timestamp.

For example:

```
today_file = 02022022

list_file = ['f_mortgage_portfolio_29012022','f_mortgage_portfolio_30012022','f_mortgage_portfolio_31012022','f_mortgage_portfolio_01022022']
```

If my `today_file` date found in the `list_file`, then `return` the file name; Else it should `return` last latest file from the list which is `f_mortgage_portfolio_01022022` based on the date value

Answer (score 1):

We can sort the list using a lambda function, descending by date, and then take the first entry:

```py
list_file = ['f_mortgage_portfolio_29012022', 'f_mortgage_portfolio_30012022', 'f_mortgage_portfolio_31012022', 'f_mortgage_portfolio_01022022']
latest_file = sorted(list_file, key=lambda x: x.rsplit('_', 1)[1][4:8] + x.rsplit('_', 1)[1][2:4] + x.rsplit('_', 1)[1][0:2], reverse=True)[0]
print(latest_file)  # f_mortgage_portfolio_01022022
```

For an explanation of the lambda function used above, starting with an input of `f_mortgage_portfolio_01022022`, we split on the last underscore to first obtain `01022022`.  Then we build a date string `20220201`, which is in a sortable ISO format.  This allows the lambda function to sort the file names descending by date.

Comment: Superb, Just in 3 lines. I have written code which involves 2 function and bit of confusing as well

Comment: ...the second line of my answer is verbose and ugly, but sometimes it's nice to use a lambda to avoid using a loop.

Comment: Still nice code, I am trying using filter and lambda , if i succeed i will post here